# Flutter: giving border radius to a container

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView builder that has containers as children and I'd like each of these containers to have rounded corners, So i wrapped it in ClipRRect and gave it a borderRadius, but the only thing affected is the shadow.

here is the result:

[image]

```
ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          child: Container(
            height: 20,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 6),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      offset: Offset(0, -5),
                      blurRadius: 10.0)
                ]),
            child: Text(
              items[index],
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
```

What am I missing?
(I know I can use the borderRadius on the BoxDecoration, but I'm wondering why this does not work as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the ClipRRect and give radius directly to the container.

If you want the shadows to stay then don't remove ClipRRect and just add the radius property to the inner container.

```
Container(
  height: 20,
  padding:
      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 6),
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)), //here
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            offset: Offset(0, -5),
            blurRadius: 10.0)
      ]),
  child: Text(
    items[index],
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white),
  ),
),
```

Edit: The rounded shadow you are getting is because of the offset that you have used for the inner container.

Edit: This might be helpful:

```
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: 10,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
      width: 50,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        child: Container(
          height: 10,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: I know I can use the boxDecoration, but I was wandering why ClipRRect is not working

Comment: That is because of the offset that you have used for the inner container.

Comment: Are you talking about the BoxShadow offset? I don't think it's related, I even removed the entire box shadow and still the container remains squared

Comment: Just tried running your code, the padding and margin values are giving the problem, comment them and it works as expected. I think you should be using EdgeInsets.fromLTRB() instead of EdgeInsets.symmetric().